# Navigation bar showing up but not right bar button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using `PageController` which shows my current VC. `PageController` is used to have a Photos app like view for scrolling photos.
On my `ViewPhotoViewController` which is in `PageControl` it shows the navigation bar on top with back button but when I assigned `rightBarButton` to it, that `rightBarButton` is not showing up.

```
let rightButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
    title: "Share",
    style: .done,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(rightButtonAction(sender:))
)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonItem
```

[image]

Comment: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...` only works if `self` has been pushed onto a `UINavigationController`. Is that the case here?

Comment: @rmaddy ViewController which is pushed to PageController is in navigation stack. Please check screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add rightBarButton on your PageController instead on your `ViewPhotoViewController`. 
Navigation bar shown on `ViewPhotoViewController` is actually of `PageController`.